# A double induction inequality

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm trying to understand an induction proof in a book ("Geometry of Banach spaces, duality mappings and nonlinear problems" by I. Cioranescu, page 202). The theorem goes like this:

> For $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m\leq n$ and $\alpha, \beta >0$ let $a_{k,j} \in \mathbb{R}$ where $0\leq k\leq m, 0\leq j\leq n$ be such that:
>   $$a_{k,j} \leq \alpha a_{k-1,j-1} +\beta a_{k,j-1}$$ 
>   Then it holds that: 
>   $$a_{m,n}\leq \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \alpha^j \beta^{n-j} \binom{n}{j} a_{m-j,0}
> + \sum_{j=m}^n \alpha^m \beta^{j-m}\binom{j-1}{m-1}a_{0,n-j}$$

The author proves this by some sort of double(?) induction. First he proves that for $m=1$ it holds that:

$$a_{1,n}\leq \beta^n a_{1,0} +\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha \beta^{j-1}a_{0,n-j}$$

for all $n$. 
Then he shows that if $m\leq n$ and the statement in the proof holds for $a_{m,n}$ then it holds for $a_{m,n+1}$.

I feel like one should have to show it for each $m$ as well I mean:
If it holds for $m\leq n$ then it holds for $m+1 \leq n$. Why is this not a necessary step in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's weird.

Let me first point out that even though you have two variables, there is no need to do induction for both, and you can do induction for just one of them, as long as you show that the theorem holds for *any* value for the other variable (for which you might be able to do a straight-up universal proof). I get the impression that this is what the author was trying to do.

However, the author is then using $m=1$ as a base case (but generalizes over all $n$) but then does the inductive step on $n$ ... that's definitely not sufficient. The author probably should have started with $n=1$ as a base case (and that should be easy to show for any $m \le n$), rather than $m=1$. And with that as a base case, and with the step going from $n$ to $n+1$, as long as the author did indeed show the step to hold for *any* $m \le n+1$, it would be a complete proof.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your reply! I'm not really sure I get the logic behind the induction scheme though. Would you mind explaining this to me?

Comment: I'm thinking (possibly very naively) that if I show $a_{m,1} \implies a_{m+1,1}$ and for an arbitrary $m\leq n$, $a_{m,n} \implies a_{m,n+1}$ if I want to get to $a_{m_0,n_0}$ I could have first "walked" up along the $\{m,1\}$ path to $\{m_0,1\}$ and then from there get to $\{m_0,n_0\}$. But in this case since $m\leq n$ I cant get beyond $\{1,1\}$ in the first step..?  And it seems to me that if I want to "take some other path" I would have to show that for any $n\geq m$ $a_{m,n} \implies a_{m+1,n}$. Maybe I'm misinterpreting/misunderstanding  what you said?

Comment: @user202542 Well, again, I believe the author was not doing double induction here, but just single induction. As such, you don't step through a grid, but simply through one of the variables ... and I believe it should be $n$. Thus, you prove that (base): for any $m \le 1$: $a_{m,n}$, and then (step) if for any $m \le n$: $a_{m,n}$, then for any $m \le n+1$: $a_{m,n+1}$. So, the author gave this step, and only the base would need to be added.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it! But still, doesn't it cause trouble if we want to show the base case $n=1$ for an arbitrary $m$ but it's only valid for $m\leq 1$? Or can we appeal to something like it being vacuously true for $m\geq 1$?

Comment: @user202542 Ha ha, that's why in my post I said that should be easy to show for any $m \le n$, because indeed that would only be $m=0$ and $m=1$ :)   So yes, you only have to check those two cases and you're done with the base case.